Meta-analysis with 2 GEO transcriptomic datasets possible?
I was searching for a set of keyterms in the GEO database. After making my PRISMA chart I ended up having 2 datasets only. My Question is can proceed with aggregating those 2 microarray datasets and perform meta-analysis?
I could extract only two NCBI Gene Expression Omnibus (GEO) Data Series (GSE IDs) for my specific research query on stroke. I will add and then average the microarray output from both datasets.
Can I pool those 2 datasets for meta-analysis?
As no more datasets are relevant for consideration, is a meta-analysis with 2 datasets valid in this scenario?
[ Please mention any References (book, article) that I can cite to support meta-analysis with 2 datasets.]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Briefly, yes. If they have a common standard between then, ensuring standardisation is performed between datasets. Otherwise, internally standardising the data sets using e.g. z-score.
